# Access an App Engine app from command line using OAuth2?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

I have an App Engine site with a URL which is marked `login:required` in app.yaml. I need to access this URL from a command-line script. How do I do that now that OAuth2 has replaced ClientLogin?

Previous questions () all end up using ClientLogin, which has been removed:

- [How do you access an authenticated Google App Engine service from a (non-web) python client?](/q/101742)
- [How to make an authenticated request from a script to appengine?](/q/10118585)
- [How do I use OAuth2 in a command line tool to access an application hosted on Google Appengine?](/q/10060758)

OAuth2 is the replacement, but when I try to use that, my script continually gets redirected to the login page.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
from google.appengine.tools import appengine_rpc_httplib2

authParams = appengine_rpc_httplib2.HttpRpcServerOAuth2.OAuth2Parameters(
  access_token=None,
  # id & secret come from http://console.developers.google.com
  client_id="FIXME",
  client_secret="FIXME",
  # I'm not sure this is the right scope
  scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin",
  refresh_token=None,
  credential_file=None
)
rpcServer = appengine_rpc_httplib2.HttpRpcServerOAuth2('example.appspot.com',
                                                       authParams,
                                                       None,
                                                       'ignored',
                                                       save_cookies=False,
                                                       auth_tries=3)
# Makes the actual GET request
result = rpcServer.Send('/some_url/', payload=None)
print result
```

(I'm using python but I'd be open to any way to do this from the command-line, even curl.)

Comment: you must pass an auth token from the command line. then on the server you need to verify the token.

Comment: Where do I get the token from? Do you have an example?

Comment: read some about oauth2 3legged flow. go to thw oauth2 playground and generate a refresh token. use the refresh token in your code to generate an access token.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the playground. Shouldn't I be able to get https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ to load a login:admin page from my app engine site? I can't. I tried with several different scopes, and on step 3 in the playground I'm able to load public URLs from my site, but login:required URLs always give a 302 redirect to https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin.  What scope should I be using?

Comment: These are the scopes I've tried:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

Comment: I also tried configuring the playground to use a custom OAuth endpoint (in the settings menu) and tried setting the URLs to those found in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/ but it is never able to get the tokens. It always gets back "400 Error: Bad Request. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request." from the authorization endpoint.

Comment: aha, I initially read your "oauth2" reference in the question which let me to think that your appengine was using oauth2, but its not. its using "google identity" which I believe is different as it sends an "id token" http://codingwithgerwin.blogspot.com/2015/04/google-sign-in-20-server-side.html

Comment: @MarkIvey How did you end up implementing this?

Comment: @Eran I never got the auth working so I gave up on the command-line tools. Instead I copied the data I needed out of the admin console.